# Como adicionar cor no hover do select option?

Tags: css

Estou tentando modificar a cor do efeito hover, porém este só funciona no firefox.

**Exemplo:**

```css
option {
  filter: hue-rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
  <option>qux</option>
</select>
```

Como posso adicionar cor em um select option cross-browser?

Comment: Para alguns comando css terem suporte em alguns browsers, tem q usar o `web-kit` para chrome e safari, `o` para opera, `ms` para IE e `moz` para firefox

Comment: O `<option>` gerado pelo HTML não é um elemento DOM normal como eu expliquei nesta pergunta [Como forçar que os elementos <option> apareçam abaixo do <select> no IE?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3827/como-for%c3%a7ar-que-os-elementos-option-apare%c3%a7am-abaixo-do-select-no-ie), sei que as perguntas são diferentes, mas a resposta lá explica o porque isto não funciona e dá uma alternativa chamada `dropkick` que deve lhe ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  vou ler, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconheço uma forma que não seja *hack*, até porque esse elemento é renderizado pelo sistema operacional. Você pode implementar seu próprio select (com `<ul>` e `<li`) ou usar um dos vários plugins que faz isso de forma *cross-browser*.

Um hack simples e que a ideia se resume em aplicar uma sombra maior que o elemento, porém voltada para dentro, usando `inset`:

```css
select option:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #9b59b6 inset
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
</select>
```

Utilizei `:checked` ao invés de `:hover` pois o segundo volta a ter a aparência *default* do elemento quando perde o hover. O `:checked` pelo permanece enquanto a opção estiver selecionada/marcada.

Eis um comparativo:

```css
select.hover option:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #9b59b6 inset
}

select.checked option:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px #9b59b6 inset
}
```

```html
<h2>c/hover</h2>
<select class='hover'>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
</select>

<h2>c/checked</h2>
<select class='checked'>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
  <option>lorem lorem lorem</option>
</select>
```